# Stop Excel from jumping to top after filtering/sorting

Tags: vba, excel

I had the simple problem that Excel always jumped to the top after a macro  ran automatically. Whenever I did a change in any cell the macro runs. However, after finishing, Excel jumps to the top. I want to stay where I edited the cell. I know there are multiple ways to fix this. My solution was one of the following.

Here my code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Selec, LastRow, LastCol, r As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set Selec = Range(Target.Address)
LastCol = Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column

If Selec.Row > Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
    LastRow = Selec.Row
    Cells(Selec.Row, 1).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Selec.Row - 1, 1))) + 1
With Cells(Selec.Row, 4).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Parameters!$A$1:$A$3"
End With
Cells(Selec.Row, 4).value = "Not Started"
Else: LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End If

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

If Not Application.Intersect(rng, Selec) Is Nothing Then
   For r = 2 To LastRow
       Select Case Cells(r, 4)
           Case "Completed"
               Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        Case "Not Started"
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case "In Progress"
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End Select
    If IsEmpty(Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol))) = False Then
        With Range("A" & r & "," & "C" & r & "," & "D" & r)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("B" & r & "," & "E" & r & "," & "F" & r)
            .WrapText = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End With
    End If
Next r
End If

'Show Only In Progress and Not Started
Worksheets("Task List").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("In Progress", "=", "Not Started"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
'Worksheets("Task List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
Worksheets("Task List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending

With Worksheets("Task List").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With
//Without one of the following lines Excel jumps to the top, but I want to stay at the end/selected cell. Uncommenting one of the following three lines solves this problem.

'Range(Target.Address).Select
'Selection.Select
'Selection.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner but I did use it in the code. If you want me put the whole macro in it let me know

Comment: No need for the whole macro. Just a [mcve]. Also, 99.9% of the time you don't *need* to `.Select` or `.Activate` anything in order to manipulate a `Range`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513).

Comment: Please refer to code just posted @MathieuGuindon

Comment: `Set Selec = Range(Target.Address)` is entirely redundant; `Target` is already the `Range` object you want to work with. Anyway I'm not seeing any `.Select` or `.Activate` call here that's used for changing the `Selection` and then working off of that, so mucho kudos for that - looks like the "jumping to the top" would be a side-effect of applying the filter/sorting? If that's the case then yes, indeed, you need to `.Select` the cell you mean to be selected; this is *exactly* the correct use-case for it.

Comment: Yes, I think it is a side effect of the sorting/filtering. I agree on the redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that the jumping up is a side effect of filtering or sorting. To prevent Excel to jump up just add the following code at the end:

```
Target.Select
```

The following two lines of code work too, but are not recommended:

```
Selection.Select
```

or

```
Selection.Activate
```

All of them should prevent Excel to jump to the top and go back to current selection.

Comment: @ScottCraner you have a better solution?

Comment: The "best" solution is dependent on exactly what your issue is, but there's no enough detail to know one way or the other. If you want to leave the user at a specific place on the sheet when a macro is done then I don't see any problem with your approach.  Selecting/Activating a range *in order to perform an operation on that range* is typically not required and can lead to tricky bugs, but as a way to navigate to a spot on a sheet it's fine.

Comment: `Target.Select` would be much more straightforward though.

Comment: I was about to upvote that revised version, but I'm pretty sure both `Selection.Select` and `Selection.Activate` are complete no-op.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Better now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this good sir! This makes a temporary view (called "TempView") at the beginning of the code, then shows that view at the end and then immediately deletes this same view.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Selec, LastRow, LastCol, r As Integer
Dim rng As Range

ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews.Add ViewName:="TempView", PrintSettings:=True, _
        RowColSettings:=True

Set Selec = Range(Target.Address)
LastCol = Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column

If Selec.Row > Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
    LastRow = Selec.Row
    Cells(Selec.Row, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Selec.Row - 1, 1))) + 1
With Cells(Selec.Row, 4).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Parameters!$A$1:$A$3"
End With
Cells(Selec.Row, 4).Value = "Not Started"
Else: LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End If

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

If Not Application.Intersect(rng, Selec) Is Nothing Then
   For r = 2 To LastRow
       Select Case Cells(r, 4)
           Case "Completed"
               Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        Case "Not Started"
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case "In Progress"
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End Select
    If IsEmpty(Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LastCol))) = False Then
        With Range("A" & r & "," & "C" & r & "," & "D" & r)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("B" & r & "," & "E" & r & "," & "F" & r)
            .WrapText = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End With
    End If
Next r
End If

'Show Only In Progress and Not Started
Worksheets("Task List").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("In Progress", "=", "Not Started"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
'Worksheets("Task List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
Worksheets("Task List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending

With Worksheets("Task List").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("TempView").Show
ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("TempView").Delete

End Sub
```